# assembly jmp to a line that doesn't exist

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, att

[image: Assembly code showing JMPQ]

For the line that says "jmpq   *0x400850", there is actually no such line has 0x400850. In this case, since I cannot jump to the place that it is mentioned, do I just skip this command and go to the command that is in the line below?

So the answers told me to type "objdump" in terminal, so I typed

```
    objdump -d ./bin-lab-ref > output.txt
```

and I got no output in the terminal.
What should I do in this situation?

Comment: `*` means indirect jump, that is through a pointer in memory. `0x400850` is the address of that pointer not the target of the jump. PS: please don't use images for code, copy-paste it as text instead.

Comment: It's an unconditional `jmp`; it never falls through.  In machine code, the `jmp` doesn't "search" for the target line or address, it just jumps there.

Comment: Note that assembly is made of *instructions,* not *commands.*  Try to use the correct terminology, this makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Use Intel syntax and you might be able to read something ;)

Comment: For the next time: please do not post pictures of code.  Always post code as text instead of as pictures!

Comment: Re: your update: of course you don't see anything in the terminal if you redirect the output for a file.  And you're not going to see `.rodata` if you use `objdump -d` instead of `-s`.  More importantly, stop posting pictures of code and your terminal; copy-paste into a code-formatted block.

Comment: I tried .       objdump -s but still doesn't output anything. I am still so confused as to how to reach the memory 0x400850.

Comment: @JuniperSohn If you type `objdump -d ./bin-lab-ref > output.txt`, then the output is in a file named `output.txt`. Have you inspected this file? Same for `-s` instead of `-d`.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `jmpq *0x400850(,%rax,8)` jumps to the value stored at address `0x400850(,%rax,8)`, not to the address `0x400850(,%rax,8)` itself.  Likely, there is a jump table at this address and `rax` selects an entry from the jump table to jump to.

Inspect the memory around `0x400850` to find out what entries the jump table has and thus where the jump goes.  You can get a dump of the executable's image using `objdump -s`.

Comment: My bad for saying "line" instead of "address"! However, I meant to say that the memory address called 400850 does not exist in this code at all. So I am guessing that there is no value saved at 400850 since the memory address does not exist in this assembly code. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: @JuniperSohn The memory address `400850` is likely not part of the `.text` section but rather of the `.rodata` section.  Since this section does not contain code (but rather data), it is not disassembled if you pass `-d`.  Inspect the output of `objdump -s` to see the content of all sections.

Comment: @JuniperSohn: it's data, not code, so `objdump -d` won't show it.  But `objdump -s` or `-D` will hexdump all sections.  Or look at it in GDB while debugging a running process started from the executable.  The address looks about right for `.section .rodata`, and it's in the same page as the instructions you're showing, so it *definitely* exists.

Comment: @PeterCordes `objdump -D` *disassembles* all sections.  to *dump* them, use `-s`.  A disassembled data section is generally not all too useful.

Comment: @fuz: thanks, I didn't know about `-s`.  In the rare cases where I wanted it, I just looked at the hex part of the `-D` output.  (edited my previous comment, though.)

Comment: @JuniperSohn If you have trouble interpreting the output of  `objdump -s`, feel free to post it and I can tell you what it means.  Make sure to post it as text, not as an image.  Never post images of text.

Comment: @fuz it's the bomb again, I bet :)

Comment: @Jester someone™ should make a canonical question/solution to all bomb labs just to get rid of these questions.  They do get a bit annoying by the time.

Comment: I am guessing it's the 64 bit version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914722/binary-bomb-phase-3-stuck/28915707#28915707)

Comment: I wrote         objdump - s ./bin-lab-ref, then it returned .       objdump - s ./bin-lab-ref

Comment: @JuniperSohn And there was no output at all?  Where did you get the disassembly posted in the question from?

Comment: @JuniperSohn Oh, you have a space between the dash and the s.  It's supposed to be `-s`, not `- s`.  So `objdump -s bin-lab-ref`.