# How to analyze the indirect jump in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, att, objdump

I am a beginner of C and assembly code who currently working on an assembly project. However, I meet some problem with the indirect jump instruction.

The jmp instruction line is:

```
4006a6: ff 24 c5 50 08 40 00    jmpq   *0x400850(,%rax,8)
```

When I go to 400850, the line is:

```
400850: ad                      lods   %ds:(%rsi),%eax
400851: 06                      (bad)  
400852: 40 00 00                add    %al,(%rax)
400855: 00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
400857: 00 b3 06 40 00 00       add    %dh,0x4006(%rbx)
40085d: 00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
40085f: 00 bc 06 40 00 00 00    add    %bh,0x40(%rsi,%rax,1)
```

Based on what I've learned, I should look at the address that stored in 400850 + 8 * rax, and jumps to that address to see instruction and do the specific operation. For example, if rax = 1, I should look at the address stored in 400858, but I cannot find 400858, and I also don't know what are the value such as "ab" mean, is it an address?

By the way, I believe this indirect jump represents an switch condition in the C code.

Comment: Start with 400857 and skip the first byte: `b3 06 40 00`, i.e. 004006b3 as a 32-bit little-endian (least significant first) word. It's often easier to look at a hex dump than disassembly when looking at data not code.

Comment: @zx485: it's not code, it's data (pointers).  You don't want to disassemble from `0x400858` either.

Comment: 0x400850 contains data, not code.  Pointers to code, 8 bytes each.  A switch/case statement is often compiled that way, each pointer in the table points to the case statement.

Answer (score 3):

`jmpq   *0x400850(,%rax,8)` is an indirect `jmp` indexing into a table of jump targets.  Yes, it's probably compiler-generated from a `switch` statement.

---

You used `objdump -D` instead of `objdump -s`, so the output breaks the hexdump up into chunks according to nonsensical decoding as x86-64 instructions, not into qword addresses.

The format is

```
starting   machine code            disassembly
address    hex byte(s)             (AT&T syntax)

400850:    ad                      lods   %ds:(%rsi),%eax
```

The byte(s) on one line go with the instruction.  `lods` is a single-byte instruction with opcode `0xad`, so the low byte of the qword at `0x400850` is `0xad`

The hexdump is all there, but not every 8-byte chunk has a numbered label.  Every byte has its own address; you just need to count from a preceding marked address to find the start of a chunk of data you want.

---

Or use `objdump -s` as recommended in [assembly jmp to a line that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302503/assembly-jmp-to-a-line-that-doesnt-exist/53303261#53303261) to get a simple hexdump of each ELF section, split into uniform size chunks.

Or from inside GDB, an `x` command.

Answer (score 0):

This address 0x400850 is a pointer table, so it's something like:
400850: 00000000004006ad
400858: 00000000004006b3
400860: 00000000004006bc

rax is and index to the pointer table. you need to know the index and find the jump address from the table.